# MongoDB C# Driver failed to run database command authenticate

Tags: c#, mongodb, authentication, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to authenticate to MongoDB with C# not through passing the Connection String/Credentials on the `MongoClient()` instance. It's like we do it on MongoDB Shell, We call `monog -> db.auth(<username>,<password>)` it means Connect to database first and authenticate after that.

1. Write C# Code
   This is my code:

   ```
   var mongoClient = new MongoClient();
   var testDB = mongoClient.GetDatabase("test");

   string username = txtUserName.Text;
   string password = txtPassword.Password;

   // Check password
   var cmd = new BsonDocument("authenticate", new BsonDocument
   {
       {"username",username },
       {"password",password }
   });

   var queryResult = testDB.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(cmd);
   ```

   My Code connect to MongoDB and call the *authenticate* Database Command ([described  Here. It's not the `db.auth()` Shell method](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/authenticate/#dbcmd.authenticate))to login with it
2. Run MongoDB with `--auth` option.
3. Run my Code.

After step 3, I encountered this problem. My code say

> Additional information: Command authenticate failed: field missing/wrong type in received authenticate command.

I have read MongoDB documents (Also the link I added above) I can't find What I was missing.

Comment: Where is the dB host name and url???

Comment: By default, it connect to localhost:27017. We don't need to specify the hostname.

Comment: Oh.. Okies..  Thanks..  I'm not familiar with c# driver connection.  In Java we have to specify,   the host name and url using ServerAddress class.  Thought it would be similar in C#

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a `JsonCommand` to call `eval` function to execute `db.auth` function like this - not tested -:

```
var command = new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>(@"{ eval: ""db.auth(\""username\"", \""password\"");"" }");
var result = db.RunCommand(command);
```